# Formatting the Clan Description in Clan Info

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have seen some clans formatting their clan info in point form, and I would like to do the same for my clan.
[image]

Does anyone have any idea how is that done?
Thanks! :)

Comment: On a side note: does that last line say no under 18 kids ?

Comment: Another thing is that you can write something on you're main computer, send it to your phone using email or google docs etc., then if you're phone's keyboard supports it copy and paste to Clash of Clans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware it's only possible by using 3rd party keyboard apps. Such as [SwiftKey](http://swiftkey.com/en/) for Android and iOS devices.

Whilst editing the text within your clan description you can popup the emoji page (Which is essentially a page of emiticons). This will allow you to add images such as the "tick" and "no entry" symbol. In SwiftKey in the emoji page there is also an "Enter" key which will add a carriage return and start a new row.

To open the emoji page you just hold down the submit button.

Others may be able to suggest other 3rd party apps which offer similar functionality.

Comment: Apple also has its own built-in keyboard for emojis. It can be accessed by adding a keyboard with a new language in settings

Comment: SwiftKey for Android works perfectly, just what I needed. The "Enter" key was probably what was needed to format it into 'point form'. Great recommendation, DMK!

Comment: I am not able to find the "Enter" key to add the carriage return, can you please point out which emoji is that?